# Eve REST Api always returns 404 when not connected via localhost

Tags: api, mongodb, rest, eve

I followed the Quick Start Guide and setup the `/people` endpoint.
It's all working fine as long as I just ask the API via `127.0.0.1`. So when I try to connect remotely via `192.168.0.206` it's giving me a 404.

I already changed `app.run()` to `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` and I've also tried `app.run(host='192.168.0.206')` without success.

When running with `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` I can connect via `localhost` but not via the remote Interface.

`strace`-ing did not helped neither reading the documentation as well :-)

I guess it depends on the `SERVER_NAME` variable, but can not figure out, what is going on there.
I tried different things there as well like `192.168.0.206:5000`, `192.168.0.206`, the hostname of the box, `0.0.0.0:5000`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: OK, I solved it by commenting out the `SERVER_NAME`variable completly. Awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `SERVER_NAME = None`, which is the default setting.